# Read a XML file using Javascript only

Tags: javascript, html, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have a XML file which needs to be read using Javascript. The text which will be read then needs to be displayed inside 3 label tags.

I can read the XML file but when I try to display the text inside the 3 labels it only shows me the last thing being read from the XML file which in this case is "Pavarotti Gala Concert".

I want to be able to print:

label 1 = "Empire Burlesque"

label 2 = "Hide your heart"

label 3 = "Pavarotti Gala Concert"

What am I doing wrong?

**XML FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Pavarotti Gala Concert</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Luciano Pavarotti</ARTIST>
    </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
           xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
           xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "text.xml", false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

        var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");

        for ( i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

            var titleName = x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].innerHTML;

            document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = titleName ;
            document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = titleName ;
            document.getElementById("text3").innerHTML = titleName ; 
    }     
}
```

**HTML**

```
<label id="text1"></label>
<label id="text2"></label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can read the XML file but when I try to display the text inside the
>   3 labels it only shows me the last thing being read from the XML file
>   which in this case is "Pavarotti Gala Concert".

In the loop you're setting `titleName` to all of `text1`, `text2`, `text3` so it makes sense that they're all equal to the last item.

Try replacing:

```
 document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = titleName ;
 document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = titleName ;
 document.getElementById("text3").innerHTML = titleName ;
```

with:

```
document.getElementById("text" + (i + 1)).innerHTML = titleName;
```

**EDIT**:

```
var titleName = x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].innerHTML;

if (tileName.indexOf('hide') !== -1) {
   document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = "Hide your heart";
   document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = "";
   document.getElementById("text3").innerHTML = "";
   break; // stop looping
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't know i could use ("text" + (i + 1)).

Comment: One question... Would it be possible to read the xml and check for the word "hide" and display the title "Hide your heart" only and not the others?

Comment: @AnotherUser I edited my answer. I _think_ that will do what you want.